# AWS SES CORS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, cors, amazon-ses

I am using S3/cloudfront hosting with custom domain (https://xxxxxx.com) and I don't have any application servers (etc. EC2).

I have contact form and find the solution I can use API from javascript (client side js). I am using webpack and reactjs.

I tried to use postmark but I have CORS issue and I couldn't use from client side js.

error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.postmarkapp.com/email' from origin 'https://xxxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

If I use Amazon Simple Email Service (SES), do I still have CORS issue?

If there any other APIs I can use without CORS issue from the client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email directly from client-side code would result in your SMTP credentials and any third-party API keys being public, so there is no way to achieve this.